# DMF and Advanced accounting structure

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have 10 dimensions in standard accounting structure and 7 dimensions defined in advanced rule.

Importing journals through DMF in excel throws error for 17 dimensions but works with 10 dimensions.

What's the right way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What is the error message? What entity are you using? Could you post some sample data that you use for import that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The issue was in generateDynamicDimension() method in DmfDimensionHelper Class.

Although It was bringing in all the dimensions values from the Segmented Entry Dimension column from Excel Sheet, it was picking only those Dimension names from the table where DimensionHierarchyType is AccountStructure and not from the Advanced Rule. I included DimensionHierarchyType of AccountRuleStructure as well. Now it's working.

```
while select Level from dimHierarchyLevel
    order by dimHierarchyLevel.DimensionHierarchy, dimHierarchyLevel.Level
        where (dimHierarchyLevel.DimensionHierarchy == dimHierarchyId
        && dimHierarchy.IsDraft == false
        && dimHierarchy.IsSystemGenerated == false
        && (dimHierarchy.StructureType == DimensionHierarchyType::AccountStructure || dimHierarchy.StructureType == DimensionHierarchyType::AccountRuleStructure) 
    join * from dimAttribute where
    dimAttribute.RecId == dimHierarchyLevel.DimensionAttribute
    exists join ledgerStructure
    where ledgerStructure.DimensionHierarchy == dimHierarchy.RecId
        && ledgerStructure.Ledger == Ledger::current()
```

This is the additional Condtition I entered:

```
dimHierarchy.StructureType == DimensionHierarchyType::AccountRuleStructure
```